# set name for a thread in RXJava android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java

I now when creating a Thread in java I can set a name for it.

```
Thread foo = new Thread("Foo");
```

Can I set name for Thread in RXJava?

Answer (score 4):

RxJava doesn't use threads by itself. It uses schedulers. Threads in existent schedulers already have pretty clear names but if you want to name threads in your custom new scheduler you can use a `ThreadFactory`:

```
fun main() {
    val pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool { runnable -> Thread(runnable, "My thread") }
    val scheduler = Schedulers.from(pool)
    Completable.fromRunnable {
        println(Thread.currentThread().name) // will print "My thread"
    }
        .subscribeOn(scheduler)
        .subscribe()
}
```